# Etymology of time and space "complexity"

Tags: terminology, algorithm-analysis, history

The word choice of "complexity" in analysis of algorithms to describe [temporal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity) and [spatial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DSPACE) resource requirements has always struct me as an odd one. These are certainly useful and meaningful concepts. This question is concerned with the language used to describe them.

Colloquially, one would probably not say that insertion sort is more "complex" than radix sort.

Is the origin and rationale of this word choice known? If so, what is it?

Comment: I for one think it the term has been carried over from complexity theory -- in a wrong way. *Problems* have complexities whereas *algorithms* have runtime (or space, or...) functions which in turn have asymptotic behaviour. When people say, "[runtime] complexity of algorithm A" they mean "the asymptotic behaviour of the runtime (function) of A". I think this is confusing use of the term "complexity" -- especially if it is supposed to refer to runtime implicitly -- and should be avoided.

Comment: I'd upvote this as an answer if you would expand a little on how the term is used in mathematics.

Comment: I have no idea if it's used in mathematics. Also, the above is just my *opinion* at this point (I'm quite certain there are people with the opinion, "if we all know what we mean we can use 'complexity' in this way!"), I can't back it with authorative references. So I don't think I should post it as an answer.

Comment: Just to clarify, by "mathematics" I was trying to refer to what you said about "complexity theory".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Complexity* refers to the complexity of the computation rather than the complexity of the algorithm. For example, Ritchie's [Classes of predictably computable functions](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1963-106-01/S0002-9947-1963-0158822-2/S0002-9947-1963-0158822-2.pdf) from 1963 "[studies] a sequence of classes of computable
functions for which a prediction of the complexity of the calculation may be
made in a comparatively simple fashion."

Hartmanis and Stearns, in their seminal 1965 paper [On the computational complexity of algorithms](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1965-117-00/S0002-9947-1965-0170805-7/S0002-9947-1965-0170805-7.pdf), also use complexity in a similar sense: "One finds, however, that some computable sequences are very easy
to compute whereas other computable sequences seem to have an inherent
complexity that makes them difficult to compute." This paper is the source of the terminology, though they cite earlier papers (like Ritchie's from 1963) which had already used complexity in this sense.